# Android, Creating DB error (SQLITE)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have gotten this message when I want to create a Database on my Android application. I am newbie with android sqlite database. now i just try to create my custom database manager and i got the error at oncreate() function.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Crear tablas
        sqlDB.execSQL(Cuenta.CREATE_TABLE);

    }
```

Could you help me please?

```
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create     application com.example.database.BDApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3451)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:124)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1012)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:890)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:648)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.example.database.DBAdapter$DBOpenHelper.onCreate(DBAdapter.java:61)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:151)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.example.database.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:26)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.example.database.BDApplication.onCreate(BDApplication.java:20)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3448)
11-05 12:21:01.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     ... 10 more
```

And my class

```
public class Cuenta {
// Nombre de la tabla
private final static String NAME = "cuenta";

// Objeto que utilizamos para acceder a la base de datos.
private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param sqlDB
 */
public Cuenta(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
    this.sqlDB = sqlDB;
}

/**
 * Clase que contiene los campos de la tabla.
 *
 * @author
 *
 */
public class Columns implements BaseColumns {
    public final static String NUM_CLIENTE = "num_cliente";
    public final static String RAZON_SOCIAL = "razon_social";
    public final static String NUM_SUCURSAL = "num_sucursal";
    public final static String DESC_SUCURSAL = "desc_sucursal";
}

// Objeto en el que guardamos todos los nombres de los campos de la tabla
// para utilizarlos posteriormente en algunos métodos.
private final static String[] COLUMNS = {Columns.NUM_CLIENTE, Columns.RAZON_SOCIAL,
        Columns.NUM_SUCURSAL, Columns.DESC_SUCURSAL};

// Sentencia para crear la tabla en la BD.
public final static String CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
        + NAME + "(" + Columns.NUM_CLIENTE + " integer not null, "
        + Columns.RAZON_SOCIAL + " varchar(15) not null, "
        + Columns.NUM_SUCURSAL + " integer not null, "
        + Columns.DESC_SUCURSAL + " varchar(15) not null)";

}
```

The DBAdapter class ..

```
public class DBAdapter {
    final static int VERSION = 1;
    final static String DB_NAME = "Miscore";

    private DBOpenHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

    // Declaramos las variables.
    Cuenta cuenta;


    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() {
    sqlDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    cuenta = new Cuenta(sqlDB);
}

public void close() {
    sqlDB.close();
}

/**
 * Comprueba si la cuenta está vacía.
 * 
 * @return true si está vacía.
 */
public boolean cuentaIsEmpty() {
    return cuenta.isEmpty();
}

/**
 * Lee los nombres de Cuenta de la BD
 * 
 * @return Cursor
 */
public Cursor getNombresCuentaCursor() {
    return cuenta.getNombres();
}

private class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Crear tablas
        sqlDB.execSQL(Cuenta.CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Need to see your DBAdapter$DBOpenHelper class since this is where the NPE is occurring.  Also - what is sqlDB?  Can't you just use the db param passed into onCreate?

Comment: Hi Michael, I just added the DBAdapter Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DBOpenHelper class has its onCreate called when you call dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().  Yet onCreate references sqlDB before it is initialized.

Instead, I think you should use the passed in SQLiteDatabase db param for onCreate to create your table.

In other words, replace this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Crear tablas
    sqlDB.execSQL(Cuenta.CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

With this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Crear tablas
    db.execSQL(Cuenta.CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, one week with this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need initialize "`Cuenta()`"

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Crear tablas
        sqlDB.execSQL(Cuenta.CREATE_TABLE); //Cuenta is Null!

    }
```